# Using Django with app engine and eclipse

Tags: python, django, eclipse, google-app-engine, pydev

We are new to the python world and would like to get started a s soon a possible and develop a little web app for app engine. We are using Eclipse + Google plugin + Pydev.

We also would like to start using Django framework and we have two questions:
1. We are looking for a good tutorial which will put us on the right track with Django + app engine?
2. We are looking for a dev tool, apperently Eclipse with Pydev support either Django project or App engine project but not together, is there any other IDE which can solve this problem?

Comment: Regarding the IDE, i would suggest using PyCharm, it's not free, but it provides great support for appengine and django (even used together) and is a really great IDE.

Comment: Thanks a lot I will take a look, if you put your comment as an answer I can at least up it.

Comment: Is this the "royal we", or are you actually more than one person?

Comment: I am actually more than one person, why is it important?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The AppEngine documentation has a section about [django integration](https://code.google.com/appengine/articles/django.html), it could be useful as a start point. There are also several other articles around the web about this topic, just google `django appengine`.

Regarding the IDE, i'd suggest using [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/), it's not free, but it has great integration for `appengine` and `Django` (even both together), and is a great IDE.

**EDIT:**

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.franciscosouza.com/2010/08/flying-with-django-on-google-app-engine/) that looks nice, i used another tutorial from this guy to create an `appengine` project using the `Flask` framework, and it was really useful.

Comment: concerning using google this is what I did first of course, the problem is I am new to django and there is a lot of material out there and I cannot judge what is good and what is not, i have a couple of tutorials opened but i am not sure they were the best.

Comment: For Django stuff only, start with its own documentation and tutorials. I wouldn't start django-on-app-engine project without knowing how django alone works. The first thing you should know, is that for now, django ORM doesn't support GAEs database (bigtables), and you have to use either GAEs ORM, or django-nonrel.

Comment: i personally love flask, it's a micro framework (doesn't provide advanced features like an ORM or forms generation, but extensions exist to add support for them), but is still very powerful. It uses Jinja2 for templating, which syntax is very similar to the Django's one.

Comment: Apparently django-nonrel is important reference.

Answer (score 0):

As @MatToufotu suggested you start with the django integration document in the appengine documentation. I would say you should stick with eclipse and pydev, as django-nonrel project created are nothing but pure django project with support for appengine, pydev can handle both of them with ease........